# copy result of a stored procedure into an existing table using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have the following stored procedure in phpMyAdmin:

[image]

I need to save the result into the following existing table:

[image]

but I don't know how to code this. The code should clear/update(?) the table every-time the stored procedure is executed and populate the last field "profile_completion_percentage" with the sum of the previous fields (excluded the id). Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

> INSERT ... SELECT Statement

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

So you can add your result very simple  to your table

Comment: Hi nbk, thank you for your answer. Do you mean add the insert code after the store procedure before the END? I Sorry for the trivial question

Comment: no INSERT INTO tablename SELECT... like the examples in the link

Comment: I think I got it thank you. How do I clean the table before inserting new data in the code? Does insert replace or append the new data? Can I incorporate  the cleaning of the target table in the stored procedure? Sorry to bother you

Comment: you delete prior to your insert, that you can do in the stored procedure, if you don't need the old data.But in big tables you should consider dropping the table and adding the same table new, that is much faster. The insert only appends like all inserts and of course it has also all general limitations.